# ARM "add" instruction with shift

Tags: disassembly, assembly, arm

I'm trying to understand how ARM `add` with shift is implemented e.g.

```
sym.imp.__libc_start_main :                                                                                                                                                           

.plt:0x000082bc 00c68fe2 add ip, pc, 0, 12; after execution ip=0x82c4
.plt:0x000082c0 08ca8ce2 add ip, ip, 8, 20; after execution ip=0x102c4
.plt:0x000082c4 48fdbce5 ldr pc, [ip, 0xd48]!
```

I wonder about the line

```
.plt:0x000082c0 08ca8ce2 add ip, ip, 8, 20;
```

it will add `#0x8000` to the ip register. My question is why `#0x8000` ?

I'd assume it will be:

```
ip = ip + (8<<20)
```

so `0x800000` but it's more like

```
ip = ip + (8<<(20-8))
```

Why is that? do I always have to substract 8 from the shift ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Circular Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) on a 32-bit system.

### Circular Shift

> In computer programming, a circular shift (or bitwise rotation) is a
>   shift operator that shifts all bits of its operand. Unlike an
>   arithmetic shift, a circular shift does not preserve a number's sign
>   bit or distinguish a number's exponent from its significand (sometimes
>   referred to as the mantissa). Unlike a logical shift, the vacant bit
>   positions are not filled in with zeros but are filled in with the bits
>   that are shifted out of the sequence.

### Understanding the code

**First Line:**
This is simply translated into `add ip, pc` because rotate operations on `#0` is still 0.
So it's actually `IP = PC  + (0 << 12) = PC + 0`

**Second Line:**
Let's take apart the opcodes and understand the problematic line:
The opcodes should be read like this because of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness): `e28cca08`

1. `e` - always execute this instruction
2. `28` - add immediate
3. `c` - Rd is the ip
4. `c` - Rn is the ip
5. `a 08` - 8 right rotated by 20

The things is, that it's not `8<<20` but instead it is `8<<(32-12)` because we are on a 32-bit system and it is a Circular Shift.

Here's a C code that showing the Circular Shift based on the example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift#Implementing_circular_shifts):

```
#include <stdint.h>  // for uint32_t, to get 32bit-wide rotates, regardless of the size of int.
#include <limits.h>  // for CHAR_BIT

uint32_t rotl32 (uint32_t value, unsigned int count) {
    const unsigned int mask = (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(value)-1);
    count &= mask;
    return (value<<count) | (value>>( (-count) & mask ));
}

uint32_t rotr32 (uint32_t value, unsigned int count) {
    const unsigned int mask = (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(value)-1);
    count &= mask;
    return (value>>count) | (value<<( (-count) & mask ));
}

int main()
{
    printf("Result: 0x%x\n",rotr32(8,20));
    return 0;
}
```

The code will output:

```
Result: 0x8000
```

Comment: I see so its rotate right and not left, thanks! BTW. typo in the anwser on line "that it's not 8<<20 but instead it is 8<<(32-12)" should be 8>>(32-12)

Answer (score 1):

It is proposed in the official document of arm
[image: arm1]

When s = 1 and RD = R15 (PC), this instruction is used to save the status register CPSR, not to do calculation
[image: arm2]